# I tried to use setTimeout but it isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Check out my `code` here: http://jsfiddle.net/qbd596tf/3/

```
function func(text1, text2)
{
    var text  = text1; 
    var length = text.length;
    var counter = 0; 
    var soFar = ""; 
    var i = setInterval(function() {
      if(counter == length)
         {
            if(text == text1) {
                text = text2;
                soFar = "";
                counter = 0;
                document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "";
            }
            else {
                text = text1;
                soFar = "";
                counter = 0;
                document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "";
            }
        }
       else {
        soFar = text.charAt(counter); 
        counter++; 
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += soFar; 
        }
    }, 250); 
}
func("HELLO HELLO", "WORLD"); 
<div id="div"></div>
```

I want to do that when word finish to display, the function will take a "break" for 5 seconds and then disappear the word and show the other word (this thing is working, the problem is with the "break").

I tried to use setTimeout but its doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to display "WORLD", wait for 5 seconds, then display "HELLO HELLO" and repeat this forever?

Comment: HELLO HELLO (text1) and then WORLD (text), and yes @bluefog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this method. I've used a setTimeout but after a clearInterval:

```
function func(text1, text2){
  var text  = text1; 
  var length = text.length;
  var counter = 0; 
  var soFar = ""; 
  var i = setInterval(showWord, 250);

  //---Function to showWord
  function showWord(){
    if(counter == length){
      if(text == text1) {
        text = text2;
        soFar = "";
        counter = 0;

        //---Clear the interval and setting a new interval
        clearInterval(i);

        setTimeout(function(){

          document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "";

          i = setInterval(showWord, 250);

        }, 5000);
      }
      else {
        text = text1;
        soFar = "";
        counter = 0;

        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "";

      }
    }
    else {
      soFar = text.charAt(counter); 
      counter++; 
      document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += soFar; 
    }
  }
}
func("HELLO HELLO", "WORLD");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/qbd596tf/12/)

Comment: Thanks, but I want that the "break" will be after one word and not aftet two, can you fix it please?

Comment: Yes, I can fix that. I'am on mobile now. I'll update the code ;)

Comment: Ready my friend. You only need to change the position of the block of code. Let me now if it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this solution ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbd596tf/10/)):

```
function setTimeToStartInterval(text2, text1, startIn){
    console.log(startIn)
    setTimeout(function(){
    startNewInterval(text2, text1, 50)
    }, startIn);
}

function startNewInterval(text1, text2, duration){
      var text  = text1; 
            var length = text.length;
            var counter = 0; 
            var soFar = ""; 
    var a = setInterval(function(){


            if(counter == length){
        console.log(2222)
                    if(text == text1) {
          clearInterval(a);
                        text = text2;
                        soFar = "";
                        counter = 0;
                        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "";
            setTimeToStartInterval(text2, text1, 5000, 'startNewInterval')
                    }
                    else {
          console.log(3333)
                        text = text1;
                        soFar = "";
                        counter = 0;
                        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "";
                    }
                }
            else {
        console.log(1111)
                soFar = text.charAt(counter); 
                counter++; 

                        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += soFar; 

                }

      }, duration)
}

startNewInterval("HELLO HELLO", "WORLD", 250);
```